# Transpose table in different sheet in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 sheet in ms. excel. For example sheet a sheet b, and sheet c. In sheet a i have table that i can input 1 or o. In sheet b i input conditional formatting with formula ='Sheet a'!I548=1, so if in sheet a cell I548 have value 1 the cell that i input the formula will have green color, else if input of cell I548 is o the cell in sheet b will fill with grey color using this formula ='Sheet a'!I548=o. in sheet c i want to transpose the table in sheet b, but the table did not transpose, and the cell with green fill and grey fill did not appear. How to solve this problem?

**Sheet b**
[image]

**Sheet c**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see it, your table in Sheet b ranges from Column A to Column H. If that is the case, than you could use the =transpose() function in Excel. DO NOTE that the range you select inside those brackets is an array. As an example, to transpose row "R" from sheet b to sheet c, do the following:

1. Since there are 8 columns in your table in sheet b, select 8 rows from any cell in sheet c (for example, select range "B27:B34")
2. Press "=" sign and then type (without quotes): "transpose("
3. Once you opened that bracket, you will see a prompt, saying to choose an array. Your array in this case is your "R" row in the table in sheet b, i.e. Range "A1:H1". Select that range.
4. Now, press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER
5. you will see that your info in the first row of the table in sheet b is transposed in sheet c. SELF CHECK: have a look at your formula in any one cell; if it has these brackets { }, then you should be fine in transposing your data.
6. Now, simply copy the formula to the right to as many columns in sheet c as you have rows in sheet b.
7. With formatting, I would suggest to simply re-apply the same formatting style to this new table in sheet c.

Comment: Thank you so much Tango_Mike. I'm sorry just reply your comment.

Comment: No problem, Real. Glad I was able to help you resolve your problem. Please mark my answer as SOLVED, given that it resolved your issue